# Unexpected non-void return value in void function for return true

Tags: swift, xcode

I am doing a test based on a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6W2Rp8Uumo&feature=youtu.be) before i start my school based major project coding. Everything went well until I faced an error.

Unexpected non-void return value in void function.

I have read other posts about this but was not able to find specifically what i need to change. The code is shown below:

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?

var MainVC:MainViewController?

func application(_application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
{
    MainVC = MainViewController(nibName: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)

    let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    window = UIWindow(frame: frame)

    window!.rootViewController = MainVC
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true //this is where the error occurs

}
```

if someone could help me fix this and explain what this error means that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method signature should have `-> Bool` at the end. This tells the compiler that the method will return a boolean value. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application).

Comment: Thanks, is it also if you add int, it would expect an integer ?

Comment: No, this is the method signature defined by apple in AppDelegate. If you write any other signature, it won't get called.